# How to prevent switching to mobile data automatically when wifi has no internet access in code

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I am making a file sharing app which can share files over wifi hotspot. There are 2 devices - Sender and receiver. In sender, I start the hotspot by calling -

```
startLocalOnlyHotspot(localOnlyHotspotCallback, handler);
```

The receiver device connects to Sender by connecting to the wifi hotspot created by Sender like so --

```
int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

And then I can connect to sender via Socket.

The problem is some devices are configured to automatically switch to mobile data and disconnect from wifi if wifi has no internet access. Local only hotspot doesn't have internet access so the receiver device automatically switches to mobile data connection for internet access and disconnects from wifi in such devices.

I need the receiver device to stay connected to wifi even if it has no internet access because I need to transfer files over wifi. How do I prevent the receiver device from disconnecting from wifi even if wifi has no internet access?